# Webhooks not working between GitLab and Hostinger

Tags: git, drupal, gitlab, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I successfully deployed my website from GitLab to Hostinger, and have set up a webhook to sync any changes. However, whenever I push any changes to GitLab I get the following message in Hostinger and the changes do not sync. What am I doing wrong?! TIA

```
Deployment start
Repository git@gitlab.com:username/project.git
Checking project directory is empty
Project directory is git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Deployment failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with **GitHub** and to fix it this is what I did:

1. in Hostinger file manager I backed up my public_html folder then removed its content.
2. I deleted my repository in Hostinger manage repositories section.
3. I added a new repository BUT this time I only clicked **Auto Deployment** don't click on deploy.
4. I made my repository as public since I am only using it for learning
5. I added the Webhooks and everytime I push to main my build branch will be auto deployed.